# slice on arguments and other objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I understand it is an anti-pattern to do:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
```

However my question is just about this line of code. I am not sure why it works. When I print out the arguments object, for example

```
function test(){
    console.log(arguments);
}

test(1,2)
//Outputs: { '0': 1, '1': 2 }
```

If I slice the arguments object

```
function test(){
    console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
}
test (1,2)
//Outputs: [1,2]
```

I would get the arguments in an array.
Even if I append something to arguments object the slice still yield the arguments in an array:

```
function test(){
    arguments['2'] = 3;
    console.log(arguments)
    console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
}

test (1,2)
//Outputs: { '0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3 }
//[ 1, 2 ]
```

If it put an object in as an object to slice.call

```
Array.prototype.slice.call({'0':1, '1':2}, 0)
```

I would get an empty array. 
Any idea why slice works on arguments object?

Comment: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/js/array.js <- I believe this is where the method is implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's an [array like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Working_with_array-like_objects) with the `length` property. If you'll add `length` to an object with numeric keys (non numeric keys are ignored), the resulting array will contain the values.

```js
console.log([].slice.call({'0':1, '1':3, a: '5', length: 2}, 0));
```

Notes:

1. `[].slice` is a shorthand for `Array.prototype.slice`.
2. [Slicing arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects) to array was widely used in ES5. Unfortunately it causes a memory leak (see [optimisation killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#32-leaking-arguments)).
3. In ES6 you can use the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) `function x(...args)` and args will be an array.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments It does say it slows down the program and stops optimization if you perform slice on arguments?

Comment: If you feel that slice is the cause of slowness, by all means replace it. However, don't do premature optimization. In addition, now days you can use `...args`.

Answer (score 0):

arguments is a special object that has length property

```
arguments = {'0':1, '1':2, length: 2}
```

if you have add the length property to your object, slice would work

try doing  typeof arguments[length] to see the length property of arguments